# Solve an equation with a finite chain of nested radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, puzzle, radicals

Solving an infinitely long square root problem is easy but how to solve this one? The equation goes like this. $$\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-x}}}} = x$$

Comment: we get the solution  as a polynomial of degree $12$

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, but this could be solved as a fixed point iteration problem. If you take the limit to infinity of iterations it then becomes an infinite chain of nested radicals.

Answer (score 0):

Its around 2.526062179 and Wolfram Alpha agrees.

You can come to the same result by visiting ["Wolfram Alpha"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3Dsqrt%284%2Bsqrt%284%2Bsqrt%284-sqrt%284-x%29%29%29%29). You can also rearrange the term stepwise:

$$
x=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-x}}}}
$$
$$
x^2-4=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-x}}}
$$
$$
(x^2-4)^2-4=\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4-x}}
$$
$$
4-(4-((x^2-4)^2-4)^2)^2=x
$$
When you now resolve the parentheses you get:
$$
\small{x^{12}-24 x^{10}-x^9+228 x^8+16 x^7-1087 x^6-88 x^5+2720 x^4+191 x^3-3380 x^2-136 x+1633} = 0
$$
Which Wolfram Alpha resolves too:
$$
x \approx 2.5260621791756334159
$$

Comment: I think a more constructive way to answer this question would be to talk about the technique in solving this question.

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis : Do you like it better now?

Comment: Yes, thanks for revising your response!

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis Would you mind removing the delete flag?

Comment: I have not placed any delete flag on this post- if someone has, it wasn't me.

Comment: I apologize for causing you trouble then.

Comment: The second to last displayed equation is not correct. $x$ satisfies $x^{12} - 24x^{10} - \cdots + 1633 = 0$. To get something correct, you need to remove the square root sign and replace the `= x` with `= 0`. You might also explain how the degree 16 polynomial equation on the preceding line becomes a degree 12 equation.

Comment: @MarkDickinsonThankyou for pointing out my flaw. Since the questions was intended as a (puzzle) a step wise solution seemed unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions.                                                                     The question was asked in a placement aptitude exam and was supposed to be solved in 4 to 5 minutes without computer or calculator.How to proceed in such scenario?